# Write a partial row with csv.DictWriter?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, python-2.x

I have a CSV file with a group of inputs.

Example:

```
A B C D
```

I want to analyze the results and output a CSV file for each row such as:

```
B C
```

The `DictReader` builds the full dictionary with the keys 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' in it as it should.
The `DictWriter` sets up the fields as it is supposed to.

However, when I attempt the send the data to the `DictWriter`, I get the error message:

```
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: A D
```

Must I delete the value entries by hand from the dictionary or is there a simple automatic way to set this up?

I am using Python 2.6.6 and am unable to update to a later version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a simple way to do it. When you create the [`csv.DictWriter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=dictwriter#csv.DictWriter) instance being used, just pass it the keyword argument `extrasaction='ignore'`—the default value for it is `'raise'`, which is the cause of the `ValueError` exception you're getting when you pass it a dictionary with keys not specified in the `fieldnames` parameter.

BTW, reading the [relevant documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/index.html) before asking SO questions is often a worthwhile endeavor—and can often provide answers without further delay.

Comment: I apologize, I apparently missed that section in the list of optional arguments or misunderstood what I was seeing.